# Rails assets pipeline difference between using config file and using manifest file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

What's  the difference between

adding css file name to assets precompile config

```
config.assets.precompile += ['foo.css', 'bar.css']
```

and put in manifest file application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require foo
 *= require bar
*/
```

?

Answer (score 0):

When you want include in HTML headers only application.css, it is the same.

But if you want to use only foo.css (without application.css and bar.css) in some page, you have to do it in config.assets, to ensure, that there will be foo.css asset standalone compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain whether Sprockets was deliberately fashioned to behave this way, but when files from the asset pipeline are included into application.css (or alternatively, application.js), they are *first* concatenated and *then* precompiled, resulting in a single file for all the files included into the respective manifest file.

In contrast, files designated to `config.assets.precompile` are compiled on a one-off, ad hoc basis. If three files are specified, then a separate precompiled file will be generated for each one (assuming it's a valid, precompilable file).

One further distinction to draw is whether Rails will precompile a file by default, or not. According to the [Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) on the asset pipeline:

> The default matcher for compiling files includes application.js, application.css and all non-JS/CSS files (i.e., .coffee and .scss files are not automatically included as they compile to JS/CSS)

So, presuming that a CSS or JS file is **not** included in the manifest, you'd need add it to `config.assets.precompile` in order for it to be precompiled and rendered.